# Woocommerce action hooks not firing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a wordpress proejct with woocommerce plugin installed.
I'm trying to add some woocommerce action hooks to my functions.php file just for testing purposes and none of them are firing

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product', 1);

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'woocommerce_show_product', 1 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'woocommerce_show_product', 1 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product', 1 );

function woocommerce_show_product() {
    echo 'GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG';
};
```

What could be the reason that woocommerce  action hooks don't fire?

Comment: Are you using a child theme? If yes try putting the code in your child theme rather than the parent theme

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense because you're only creating the action. You never called it. To call the created action, use the following code : `do_action('action_name');`

```
   do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product', 1 );
```

Comment: I tried both to add the code in my child theme and also to use do_action as you said but still nothing. I also tried do_action('woocommerce_show_product); which supposed to just fire the function right? And it's still not doing anything

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_show_return_policy', 20 );

function bbloomer_show_return_policy() {
    echo '<p class="rtrn">30-day return policy offered. See Terms and Conditions for details.</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's too late for the questioner with the hint, but maybe I can help someone else because I had the same problem today. My problem was that I forgot to add Woocommerce support in the theme:

In function.php you need to add support for woocomerce:

```php
function add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support('woocommerce');
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'add_woocommerce_support');
```

Without this woocommerce remove some hooks.